# Simple drawing of a rectangle with Electron and JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to very simply draw a rectangle on a canvas with Electron but none of the code is running after the line "var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")". I'm brand new to JS and Electron. At first I thought that maybe the JS code was being run before the canvas was rendered, but I don't think that's the case here. Here is app.js:

```
function initDraw(canvas) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

and here is index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .aligncenter {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #canvas {
        width:2000px;
        height:2000px;
        border: 10px solid transparent;
    }
    .rectangle {
        border: 1px solid #FF0000;
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
      initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using macOS and Electron. I'm sure the solution is very simple, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: cant tell if its loading app.js, but it should be `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`, not a div

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks! I suspected it was something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

the element containing the id "canvas" is a div. but it should not be a div. It should be a canvas.

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```